# Getting every <td> in <tr> by index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find all td's by index (1) in every row. How can I accomplish this?

My HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>Maandag</th><th>Dinsdag</th><th>Woensdag</th><th>Donderdag</th><th>Vrijdag</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td></td><td>THIS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>THIS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>THIS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>THIS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var index = 1;
$('tbody').children().children(':eq(' + index + ')');
```

This code doesn't work because it gets all children of the row and THEN gets the index. I need every second TD in every row.

Comment: `Array.from($('table').prop("rows"), row => row.cells[1])`

Comment: @Bergi That is a slick solution. Learned some things of that little piece of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
var index = 1;
$('tbody').find('td:nth-child('+(index+1)+')');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XpAsY/)

Comment: @Pawel_W sorry I didn't get you

Comment: Should have known this! Thanks Arun P Johny!

Answer (score 2):

Or just plain [vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/)

```js
var index = 2,
    tdElArr = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr td:nth-child(' + index + ')');

// to test this:
for(var i=tdElArr.length;i--;){
    tdElArr[i].style.backgroundColor = '#cdedff'
}
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>Maandag</th><th>Dinsdag</th><th>Woensdag</th><th>Donderdag</th><th>Vrijdag</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td></td><td>THIS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>THIS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>THIS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>THIS</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I always appreciate a non-jQuery solution!

Answer (score 1):

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/LZH87/

```
$('tbody').children().children('td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    $(this).css({background: 'blue'});
});
```

I just added the css background blue to confirm that it works

Comment: You don't need `.each`.

Answer (score 1):

This could also work ([jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/westman/LZH87/1/))

```
$('tbody').children().each(function(){
    $(this).find('td:odd').css({background: 'red'});
});
```

It's using the [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) or [:even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selectors in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('tbody').find('tr').each(function(i){
    alert($('tbody').find('tr:eq('+i+')').find('td:eq(1)').text())
})
```

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/YT3CD/